# .NET bug. How to fix?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my complex program `TextBox.Text` is interconnected with `Grid.Width`.
When I clear `TextBox`, .NET is crashed.

The problem is that inside `TextBox.TextChanged` I set `Grid.Width` and inside `Grid.SizeChanged` I set `TextBox.Text`. Thus, `TextBox.Text` is set inside two nested event handlers.

Could anyone help to fix this bug without `Timer` or `Binding`?

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0x6c05e4ad, on thread 0x2844. The error code is 0x80131623.
>   This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable
>   portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user
>   marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the
>   stack.

I created a test WPF app to check this bug separately.

XAML:

```
<Grid Height="350">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="350" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="350" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0"
          x:Name="grid"
          Width="300"
          Height="300"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          Background="Red"
          SizeChanged="grid_SizeChanged" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
          x:Name="text"
          Text="300"
          TextChanged="text_TextChanged" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
private void grid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    text.Text = grid.Width.ToString();
}

private void text_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (text.Text == "")
        grid.Width = double.NaN;
}
```

Comment: Why would you set it to `NaN` when you clear it? I'm sure that's *causing* the "bug" in the runtime, try changing it to something that **is** a number, like 0.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(new Grid().Width.ToString());` shows `NaN`, so it means `Auto`

Comment: Why not use binding directly in your XML ? 
<TextBox x:Name="text" Text="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=Width}" />

Comment: I copied your code into a small test application & I get no problems.

Comment: Because it is very complicated program using `JavaScript` and `C ++`, and they do not support `Binding`

Comment: This code does not work on some computers, not everyone.

Comment: So what is the difference between the ones it works on & the ones it fails on? Operating system? .NET version? anything else?

Comment: This answer suggests looking at event logs : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181673/weird-exception-on-collection

Comment: `Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5`
It works on `Windows 8.0 Pro [Version 6.2.9200]`.
It doesn't work on `Windows 8.1 Embedded [Version 6.3.9600]` and `Windows 8.1 Industry Pro [Version 6.3.9600]`

Comment: When I add `MessageBox.Show(text.Text);` at the end of `grid_SizeChanged`, the error changed to `Dispatcher processing has been suspended, but messages are still being processed.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using the Dispatcher:

```
private void grid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //text.Text = grid.Width.ToString();
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => text.Text = grid.Width.ToString()));
}
```

Thank you all for "help" and negative rating.